# C++ and Python analogs for Pascal's typed binary files

Tags: python, c++, pascal, binaryfiles

There is a convenient thing in Pascal which is typed binary files.

**Description from [Free Pascal wiki](http://wiki.freepascal.org/File#Typed_binary)**

> The type `file of <type>`, where `<type>` is any simple type (no references/pointers) or record type, is a binary file representing a sequence of  values. For example, you can have files that are a sequence of integers, floating-point values, or records (as long as all record fields are also simple types).

I wonder if I can use something like this with Python data types, C++ classes or just C-like plain structs, i.e. with something more complex than primitive number types.

Comment: Maybe the [struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) packge is what you are looking for.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - That seems to be what I need. I'm still interested in c++ analog though

Comment: For C++, the keyword I'm thinking of is serialization. And of course, boost has a thing for it: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

Comment: @Lagerbaer - I need to use binary files. That's the point of work

Comment: Yeah and from that link: "Here, we use the term "serialization" to mean the reversible deconstruction of an arbitrary set of C++ data structures to a sequence of bytes." Sequence of bytes = binary files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python(3) basically has three types of files;

- text
- binary
- raw

See the documentation for the [io](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) module.

Using binary files and `struct` you could basically create iterators over arbitrary file types.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, the file layout is determined by the programmer.
The language provides a `binary` mode in which data is not translated to or from the file.

Also, some types may contain *pointers* which are valid when written to a file because the items pointed to may be loaded into different locations by the operating system.

Search the internet for "c++ serialization".

Comment: My guess is that the OP wants to define a file of packed structs without automated types. How would one do that in C++? Pascal differentiates between a binary file from which you manually read structs, and a file that contains _only_ a certain struct in a language enforced way.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort:  In C++, files don't contain types.  You read a quantity of bytes from the file.  You can read them into a variable (record).

Comment: Yes, that was what I guessed from my limited plain C experience (but wasn't sure for C++). C++ doesn't have proper typed file support. But in Pascal serialization of a struct to to "file of byte" or to file of <somestruct>  are different things. E.g. a seek on a "file of <struct>" will be in granularity of sizeof(struct), so seek(f,2) will select the third record etc.Raw files can have granularity too (e.g. pagesize 4096/8192 bytes for memory mapped files is a practical example)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews How do I read bytes directly into a variable?

Comment: You use the block read method, [std::ifstream::read](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read).  You can use `sizeof` for POD types.  For records, you should perform I/O on individual data members.  *Search the internet for "C++ serialization"*.